# How to use Eclipse collection in Spring boot ResponseEnity in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, eclipse-collections

So I need help in using java eclipse collections as part of the response using the spring boot Response Entity JSON . I have tried using the generic way but I get a response exception error that it failed to convert to java ArrayList type so can anyone provide an example for a normal rest endpoint that uses eclipse collections data instead of java collections list?

here is an example code

```
 @GetMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<MutableList<Person>> getData() {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(Map.of(
                    "success", true,
                    
                    "data", Map.of(
                            "users", personService.getUsers()
                    )
            ));

}
```

Comment: Can you post snippet of what you are trying to do and how ?

Comment: @Harsh i have out an example

Comment: You could try the eclipse-collections jackson module from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/

Comment: Could you please provide an exception stack trace?

Comment: What type does `personService.getUsers()` return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instructions for enabling [eclipse-collections](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatypes-collections/) Jackson module that adds Json serialization support for Eclipse Collection Types:

By default Spring MVC MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter will create its own ObjectMapper with default options using Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder. As per [Spring Boot docs 76.3](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html) Customize the Jackson ObjectMapper chapter:

> Any beans of type com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module are
> automatically registered with the auto-configured
> Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder and are applied to any ObjectMapper
> instances that it creates. This provides a global mechanism for
> contributing custom modules when you add new features to your
> application.

so it should be enough to register eclipse collections module as a bean:

```
@Bean
public EclipseCollectionsModule eclipseCollectionsModule() 
{
    return new EclipseCollectionsModule();
}
```

Comment: This isn't working if you're using RestClient with Spring Boot 3.2.1. It gives a serialization exception even if you've registered EclipseCollections Jackson module

Answer (score 0):

Replace your return expression with the following code:

```
return ResponseEntity.ok(personService.getUsers().stream().collect(Collectors2.toList()));
```